# Locating a web element using xPath by text is split across several spans

Tags: html, xpath, html-parsing

Can somebody help me find an xPath, that would locate an element based on its text, which is split across several spans? When I use text() function, it seems to only find the starting sequence of the element text until the first span.

For example in a following scenario I would like to locate only the first `<h5>` and not the other one. That is to find an element, which displays a text "A xxx B"

```
...
<h5>
A
<span>xxx</span>
B
</h5>
...
<h5>
A
<span>xxx</span>
C
</h5>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your criterion is: are you looking for `h5` that contains "A where B"?

Comment: Yes, this is an example. The problem is I do not know to find the part of the text in h5 behind the <span>, where either B or C could be and which is the information I need to distinguish between the two elements.

Comment: Could you share, what is wrong with my solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match all `h5` and only copy / do whatever with the nodes, if they meet a certain condition. This condition is to check the last text node (or `[2]` for second), whether it is equal to some hardcoded string. You may need to use `normalize-space()` to eleminate whitespace from the text node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/h5"/>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="h5">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(./text()[last()]) = 'C'">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
  <h5>
    A
    <span>xxx</span>
    C
  </h5>
</result>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it is possible (and in this case necessary) to index the text inside a single element. Using indexes is perhaps the easiest solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
h5[1]
```

You can select a certain item of a collection by using an index.

Comment: Thank you, but mine was only an example. In reality I cannot predict the index of the heading I need. The elements can appear in any order. Its text is the only relevant locator I can rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `descendant-or-self::node()` to get the whole text from the `h5` tag, handle newlines and spaces with `normalize-space()`:

```
//h5[normalize-space(descendant-or-self::node()) = 'A xxx B']
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath "//h5[normalize-space(descendant-or-self::node()) = 'A xxx B']"
<h5>
    A
    <span>xxx</span>
    B
</h5>
```

where `index.html` contains:

```
<div>
    <h5>
        A
        <span>xxx</span>
        B
    </h5>
    ...
    <h5>
        A
        <span>xxx</span>
        C
    </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar situation:

```
<button title="Create New" accesskey="N">
Create
<span class="X">N</span>
ew
</button>
```

It create button with text "Create New".
To find this button you can use

```
 //button[descendant-or-self::* = 'Create New']
```

This is simpler version of **alecxe** answer (if you don't have space inside)